# Replacing characters got from javascript

Tags: java, regex, string, flickr, replaceall

i'm making a program that extracts all the pictures from a flickr set. I found in the code a big String with every picture link, the problem is this:

The links have the next format:

```
https:\/\/c2.staticflickr.com\/4\/3925\/14562233192_3fe2b8fe1b_s.jpg
```

but i'm unable of removing the '\' character, despite using the "\" escape sequence.

My replacing code is the following, ret contains a lot of links separated by '\n':

```
ret =ret.replaceAll("\\", "");
```

what in the world am i forgetting?

My error stackTrace is this:

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal      error near index 1
 \
 ^
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use 4 slashes instead of 2. Like this - `ret =ret.replaceAll("\\\\", "")`. You need 1 for java, one for regex engine, and two to parse it *literally* (removing the special meaning).

Comment: You are instantly and permanently my favourite person in the world

Comment: True! Regex is used as input in `repeatAll` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String), so it's not enough to escape it once, gotta be sure regex isn't going to escape it too haha. Check some useful functions such as `Matcher.quoteReplacement` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) and `Pattern.quote` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

The `\` is a special character in regexes, which is used to escape other special characters. Thus, to match a `\`, you need your regex to be `\\`. Since you need to escape the backslashes again (this time for the Java string), you need to call `ret =ret.replaceAll("\\\\", "");`.

Comment: If you read, that is exactly what i did, but thanks for the try.

Comment: Wow, I definitely made a typo there. Fixed it with 4 `\`s.